# Unable to remove tortoise svn link from a drive. Mistakenly checked-out the whole drive instead of a specific folder

Tags: tortoisesvn

I gave D: drive as my local repository while checking out instead of giving a folder.

I.e unknowingly, I gave the url path as D: drive for svn check out. Now all the folders inside my drive have been added to the svn repository. And the drive is now fully in svn control. How to rectify this problem?

I tried exporting the folders inside the drive to remove the link. And I tried to delete the folders. But the problem prevails still.

Comment: delete the .svn folder (or _svn) and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

To unlink your drive from subversion, delete .svn folder from it.
I suppose you have not committed your changes on SVN  server. If you have, then delete from there too.